# How to modify existing jar file?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, jar

I need to modify gwt-log.jar file which is downloaded from maven repository. I need to change log4j version  in this jar.

I have unzipped this jar and trying to modify it with  intellij idea  but dependences are not resolved.
So, how can I do  it with intellij idea  and build jar again?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Fork and clone https://github.com/fredsa/gwt-log using the terminal.
- Open the IDE welcome page.
- Click `Open` and select the `pom.xml`:
  [image]
- Select `Open as Project` and `Trust Project`.
- Wait for Maven to finish the job.
- Make changes.
- Build a JAR file from sources.